# Set 2 form fields based on dropdown selection tied to 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I need some Javascript help here

I have a simple array

```
 var price_eFile = [  //Prov Fee, Gov Fee
 [49.99,0], //ON 
 [99.99,351.50], //BC
 [79.99,250.00] //SK
 ];
```

And some values I use in a form calculator

```
price_eFileProv = 0;
price_eFileGov = 0;
```

And the following HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-6">
        <select name="eFileProv"  class="form-control" id="eFileProv"    onChange="checkeFileJur();Form_Calculator();">              
              <option selected>select province</option>
              <option id="CAN-ON" value="ON">Ontario (ON)</option>                     
              <option id="CAN-BC" value="BC">British Columbia (BC)</option>               
              <option id="CAN-SK" value="SK">Saskatchewan (SK)</option>

        </select>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
          <input name="dis_price_eFileProv" type="text" class="form-control fcalc" id="dis_price_eFileProv" value="" readonly>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
          <input name="dis_price_eFileGov" type="text" class="form-control fcalc" id="dis_price_eFileGov" value="" readonly>
      </div>
```

So if they select option2 I need to set dis_price_eFileProv and price_eFileProv  as well as dis_price_eFileGov and price_eFileGov  to their respective values based on the dropdown selection and corresponding array so that the second option would set the first two variables to 99.99 and the other 2 variables to 351.50
Note: I am not using jquery or anything like that, just good ole Javascript in the rest of my form calculator.

Comment: The order of the array elements isn't the same as the order of the dropdown options. How is it supposed to know the correspondence?

Comment: Instead of an array, use an object whose keys are the option values, and values are the two prices. Then when the user selects an option, you get the value of the `<select>` and use this as the index into the object. Then you can set the variables appropriately.

Comment: Don't forget that when you actually implement the purchase, you need to calculate the price on the server, not the client. Otherwise, the user could go into DevTools and change the price.

Comment: Ok I fixed my dropdown html that was wrong

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would suggest is to not use an array but use an object/hash instead.

When using an array you're just arbitrarily connecting numeric indexes to values with no apparent meaning. You are also tied to the order and any changes might require multiple adjustments across the code.

With a hash you can map to your values with meaningful strings.

Here's one way to structure a hash for your use case:

```
var price_eFile = {  //Prov Fee, Gov Fee
  'ON': {
   'prov': 49.99,
   'gov': 0
  },
  'BC': {
   'prov': 99.99,
   'gov': 351.50
  },
  'SK': {
   'prov': 79.99,
   'gov': 250.00
  }
};
```

Now it's easy to determine which prices are needed whenever a selection happens:

```
function FormCalculator(e) {
  var state = e.target.value;      // obtain the state from the selected option value
  var prices = price_eFile[state]; // obtain the prices from the state name

  // set proper prices to proper places
  inputForProv.value = prices.prov;
  inputForGov.value = prices.gov;
}
```

All that is left is to attach the above function to the DOM.

Comment: He already attaches the function with `onChange="checkeFileJur();Form_Calculator();"` Just rename your `onSelectChange` function to `FormCalculator`

Comment: Not sure I understand what's going on here: 

// set proper prices to proper places
     inputForProv.value = prices.prov;
     inputForGov.value = prices.gov;


Should I change to? 
    dis_price_eFileProv.value = price_eFileProv;
    dis_price_eFileGov.value = price_eFileGov;

Comment: You need to grab the inputs from the DOM using something like document.querySelector and then give them the values on every selecrion change.

Comment: I'm a total noob with this stuff. I am getting type error e is undefined...